# Batch FOR /F loop won't read relative directory

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, text

I have a simply FOR /F loop which strips out all but one line of a text file:

```
for /f "skip=12 tokens=* delims= " %%f in (.\NonProcessed\*.txt) do (
   > newfile.txt echo.%%f
   goto :eof
)
```

But when I run, I get the result:

```
The system cannot find the file .\NonProcessed\*.txt
```

The for loop works fine if I enter a fully qualified path to the text file within the brackets, but it can't handle the relative link I have in there. I've been able to use the exact same relative link in another standard for loop in a different batch file running in the same directory without any issues. I can't understand why it won't work! Please help.

EDIT: For comments, code I'm using now is

```
for %%f in (.\NonProcessed\*.txt) do (
  echo f is %%f
  for /f "usebackq skip=12 tokens=* delims= " %%a in (%%f) do (
    echo a is %%a
    > %%f echo.%%a
    goto :continue
  )
:continue
  sqlcmd stuff here
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but `for /f` does not allow you to do that. And no, the problem is not the relative path to files but the wildcard.

According to [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754900%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), you have the syntax case

```
for /F ["ParsingKeywords"] {%% | %}variable in (filenameset) do command [CommandLineOptions]
```

For this case, documentation states `The Set argument specifies one or more file names`. You can do

```
for /f %%a in (file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt) do ...
```

but wildcards are not allowed.

If you don't know the name of the file you want to process, your best option is to add an additional `for` command to first select the file

```
for %%a in (".\NonProcessed\*.txt"
) do for /f "usebackq skip=12 tokens=* delims= " %%f in ("%%~fa"
) do (
   > newfile.txt echo(%%f
   goto :eof
)
```

When executed,  the `goto` command will cancel both `for` loops so you end with the same behaviour you expected from your original code.

**edited** to adapt code to comments

```
@echo off

    set "folder=.\NonProcessed"

    pushd "%folder%"
    for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=:" %%a in (
        ' findstr /n "^" *.txt ^| findstr /r /b /c:"[^:]*:13:" '
    ) do (
        echo Overwrite file "%%a" with content "%%c"
        >"%%a" echo(%%c
    )
    popd
```

Read all the files in the folder, numbering the lines. The output for the first findstr command will be

```
filename.txt:99:lineContents
```

This output is parsed to find the line 13, the resulting data is splitted using the colon as a separator, so we will end with the file name in `%%a`, the line number in `%%b` and the line content in `%%c`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Your solution is actually what I already tried! Unfortunately, the goto:eof will cancel both loops on the first iteration. Obviously I want to loop through all text files in the folder with the same behaviour.

There is more code outside the 'text alteration loop' but within the outer loop (it executes some SQL). In order to get to that, I've just made another bookmark outside the inner loop before that extra code, and altered `goto:eof` to `goto:continue`.

That appears to almost have the correct behaviour (it works with just one file).

Comment: However, for some reason with more than one file, it struggles with spaces in the file name (but only when it reaches in the inner loop). I'll get the code in a minute...

Comment: Hmm, if I have more than one file in the folder it works on the first, but clearly doesn't run the outer loop to select the next file once it's finished. Is this something to do with my `goto:continue`?

Comment: @user3804579, sorry, the question did not state cleary if you need to iterate over more than a file or if you simply do not know a priori the name of the file. Ok, several files, what should end in `newfile.txt`? Is it just a temporary file for each iteration?, should it contain one line from each file? ....

Comment: Okay, the actual requirement is for each file in the folder, rewrite the file with only the contents of the 13th line

Comment: So in the end you start with files: File1.txt and File2.txt, both with loads of lines of text in them, but afterwards you still have File1.txt and File2.txt but with only the 13th line from the originals.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET FILES_LIST=files_list.config
DIR /b .\NonProcessed\*.txt>!FILES_LIST!
for /f "skip=12 tokens=* delims= " %%f in (!FILES_LIST!) do (
   > newfile.txt echo.%%f
   goto :eof
)
IF EXIST "!FILES_LIST!" DEL "!FILES_LIST!"
```

I did not check how your's FOR works, just added my additions/corrections to it.... Hope it will work for you.
Best regards!